# i18next library taking too much time in initialization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, localization, i18next

I was trying to integrate my application with i18next library to support localization. I am taking few decisions on the detected language so this is lying in the critical path of the app launch.

What I observed that below call is taking around 200-300 ms. I wish if I could get a callback just after detecting the language and not at the actual downloading of resources(/local/*.json)

```
await i18n
.use(backend)
.init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
})
```

I tried below event callbacks but all of these are coming after 200-300 ms later.

```
i18n.on('initialized', function(options) {
  console.log("i18n","initialized")
})


i18n.on('loaded', function(loaded) {
  console.log("i18n","loaded")
})

i18n.on('languageChanged', function(lng) {
  console.log("i18n","language detected")
})
```

When I am trying to do such language detection at my end it is done in less than 1 ms. I was just trying to figure out what is making this library perform slow.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the used i18next backend, it is not only detecting the language, it is also loading (fetching) the appropriate translation resources.
Without an i18next backend (all in memory) you'll see it takes way less time: https://www.i18next.com/how-to/add-or-load-translations#add-on-init

Comment: @ 

Yes that was my first thought as well. I see that if I remove the backend option then it takes lesser time. I am seeing below two possible solutions:

1. Create two instances one without backend and one with backend option. First one will be used to detect the language while second one will be used for translation.
2. Not providing backend option in first call and later attach it
3. partialBundledLanguages: true, ns: [] and later load the resouces

not sure how can I achieve 2 or 3. 1 seems doable but language detection task common between the two instances.